# python multiprocessing - use Pool.map on complex data structures

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let's say I have the following (not so complex) data structure:

```
d = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [5,6,7,8]}
```

and I want to apply the following function to each list element:

```
def func(x):
  return x+1
```

and get back the same structure:

```
d = {'A': [2,3,4,5], 'B': [6,7,8,9]}
```

Is there a simple way to apply the Pool.map logic to structures other than a list? I could iterate over dict keys and treat every list separately, but this may result in non-optimal usage of the CPUs, for example if func takes a long time to run for certain inputs. To avoid this, one needs to collect all inputs together, but then you also need to collect them back and produce the original structure.
The only solution I was able to come up with is by keeping the dict key and passing it to the mapped function (using starmap), only to return it as is. Something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

d = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [5,6,7,8]}

def func(x, key):
  return x+1, key

with Pool(3) as pool:
  results = pool.starmap(func, [(val, key) for key in d for val in d[key]])
  new_d = {}
  for res in results:
    if res[1] not in new_d:
      new_d[res[1]] = [res[0]]
    else:
      new_d[res[1]].append(res[0])
```

But this seems a bit messy. Is there a simpler/better way to do it?

Comment: You seem to have two conflicting goals. If `func` is processing a single element of a list at a time, which is a value of a key, then you need to have the results returned in the order in which the tasks are submitted. This implies that you need to use one of the methods in the map family. Yet you seem to be concerned about what happens if one of the function calls taking *too* long resulting in suboptimal CPU usage. Assuming the total number of tasks is not too great, force a *chunksize* of 1. In that way I would think no processor would ever be idle.

Comment: One further thought: There is no problem with `map` just because it doesn't return results until all the processes complete because there is nothing you can really do as far has having a complete, new update dictionary until all the processes complete and all the new values have been calculated. Yes, it would be ideal if these values *could* be computed in key value order and within key value order, list value order, i.e. the order in which they were submitted, but you have no control over that. But once all the values are available, it shouldn't take a lot of time to construct the dictionary.

Comment: I also think that @python_user prematurely deleted their answer. As long as a *chunksize* argument of 1 is provided to the `map` call (which would probably be the computed value for this small example *iterable* since `None` as a default is being used), I don't think you would have to worry about a processor being idle. I am not sure why anyone is explicitly specifying a pool size of 3, however. I would also have tried using `map_async` in their answer for better parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments to your question about using *chunksize=1* with methods in the `map` family. Here I am improving on the deleted answer of @python_user by using `map_async` so that I can get better parallelization:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(x):
    return x + 1

def main():
    d = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [5,6,7,8]}

    with Pool() as pool:
        results = {key:pool.map_async(func, value, chunksize=1) for key, value in d.items()}
        new_d = {key: results[key].get() for key in results}

    print(new_d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
{'A': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [6, 7, 8, 9]}
```